# PyQt4 window disappears when back end runs and re-appears when finished

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am very new to PyQt4 and was learning how to integrate it with my Python code at the back-end. The way I did it, the front-end looks just fine and takes all the input I need. When the processing starts, that is when the back-end scripts run, the window disappears and reappears when all my back end scripts have finished. The window is supposed to show the status of the on-going process (at the back end).
Please help me with this.

A  Button on Win2 makes it switch to Win4 and that is when Win4 disappears and reappears once all the back end processing is done.

Code snippet:

```
class Win2(QtGui.QMainWindow, w2):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.move(500,200)
    self.window1 = None
    self.window4 = None
    self.window5 = None
    self.window6 = None
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showWin4)
    self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.showWin5)
    self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.showWin6)
    self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.openIP)
    self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.opencred)
    self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.showWin1)

def openIP(self):
    self.filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
    #print filename
    self.label_7.setText(self.filename)


def from_alldevicesrun(self):
    #print check_port.all_ips
    with open(self.filename, "rb") as csvfile:
        iprow = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n')
        for [ip] in iprow:
            #print ip
            from_alldevices.ips.append(ip)

    csvfile.close()

    from_alldevices.main()


def opencred(self):

    self.filename1 = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
    #print filename1

    self.label_9.setText(self.filename1)

def see_cred(self):
    '''
    import __builtin__
    __builtin__.x = self.filename1
    import check_credentials_both
    '''
    cmd = ['python', 'c.py' ]
    cmd_out = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]



def showWin4(self):
    self.close()        
    if self.window4 is None:
        self.window4 = Win4()       
    self.window4.show()
    self.window4.set_status_7('Ongoing')
    self.from_alldevicesrun()
    self.window4.set_status_7('Done')
    self.window4.set_status_13('Ongoing')
    self.see_cred()
    self.window4.set_status_13('Done')
    self.window4.set_status_8('Ongoing')
    self.window4.get_data_from_server()
    self.window4.set_status_8('Done')
    self.window4.set_status_9('Ongoing')
    self.window4.SSH_into_nw()
    self.window4.set_status_9('Done')
    self.window4.set_status_10('Ongoing')
    self.window4.extract_mac()
    self.window4.extract_lldp()
    self.window4.port_channel_change()
    self.window4.final_algo()
    self.window4.set_status_10('Done')
    self.window4.showWin10()


def showWin5(self):
    if self.window5 is None:
        self.window5 = Win5(self)
    self.window5.show()

def showWin6(self):
    if self.window6 is None:
        self.window6 = Win6(self)
    self.window6.show() 

def showWin1(self):
    self.close()
    if self.window1 is None:
        self.window1 = Win1(self)
    self.window1.show()


class Win4(QtGui.QDialog, w4):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.move(500,200)
    self.window10 = None
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_graphandWin8)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showWin10)
    self.window8 = None 

def show_graphandWin8(self):
    #self.close()
    if self.window8 is None:
        self.window8 = Win8(self)
    self.window8.show()
    cmd = ['python', 'dc.py' ]
            cmd_out = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]          

def set_status_7(self,text):
    self.label_7.setText(text)


def set_status_8(self,text):
    self.label_8.setText(text)

def set_status_9(self,text):
    self.label_9.setText(text)

def set_status_10(self,text):
    self.label_10.setText(text)

def set_status_13(self,text):
    self.label_13.setText(text)


def get_data_from_server(self): 
    get_data_from_servers.main()

def SSH_into_nw(self):
    import SSH_and_telnet_nw    
    SSH_and_telnet_nw.main()

def extract_mac(self):
    cmd = ['python', '123.py' ]
            cmd_out = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

def extract_lldp(self): 
    cmd = ['python', 'qwe.py' ]
            cmd_out = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

def port_channel_change(self):
    import change_to_port_channel
    change_to_port_channel.main()

def final_algo(self):   
    cmd = ['python', 'abc.py' ]
            cmd_out = subprocess.Popen( cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]



def showWin10(self):
    if self.window10 is None:
        self.window10 = Win10(self)
    self.window10.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Win2()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know I answered this, but can you clarify what exactly is the problem you are seeing? And what the desired behavior is?

Comment: Thank you for the help. So the desired behaviour is that when the back end script is running, my GUI should not disappear and show me the status (as text on screen) of the scripts running. The problem is that when the back end scripts which are imported using 'import backendscript' are run backendscript.main(), the window disappears and reappears when the script is over. I do not want the GUI to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`hide()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hide) not [`close()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close). When you are calling `self.close()` you are making the `QMainWindow` stop and potentially be set for deletion. With `hide()` it will just make the Window invisible until you want to `show()` it again.

```
def showWin4(self):
    self.hide() #This should be a hide not close
    if self.window4 is None:
        self.window4 = Win4()       
    self.window4.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried hide(), it didn't help either. The GUI window still disappears when the back end script is running.

Comment: I think what I need is two parallel threads, one running front end and one running back end at the same time

Comment: You are probably right with needing another thread to run the background processes. Typically the symptom that I have seen of that is that the GUI "freezes" not disappears which is why I didn't think that was the issue. I have been down the threading route and I can recommend starting with the model of `moveToThread` and not the subclass model, I had a lot of headaches with the latter and had to refactor to get to the former. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. :)